# Error using telegram.ext python library (TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue')

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to create a telegram bot with python script.

but I got an unexpected error.

I used a Linux-based VPS located in Germany to run my script.
I installed all the necessary libraries like "telegram".
and the python version that I tried was 3.8.10

This is the code that I tried:

```
import telegram.ext

Token= "S*************************************nd"
    
updater= telegram.ext.Updater(Token)




def start (update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("hello!")



dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler("start",start))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/telegrambot/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    updater= telegram.ext.Updater(Token)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'
```

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram.ext.Updater.update_queue:%7E:text=telegram.Bot-,update_queue,-%5Bsource%5D)  but didn's undrestand what to do with 'update_queue'.
And I've read questions on StackOverflow that might seem the same as mine. none of them was related to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    from telegram import Update

    from telegram.ext import (

    Application,

    CommandHandler,

    ContextTypes,

)

async def start(update, context):
    await update.message.reply_text('Hola, mucho gusto')

def main():
    
    application = (

        Application.builder()

        .token("**********")

        .arbitrary_callback_data(True)

        .build()

    )

    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. but I got an error with this code too.